# Platform events on Salesforce1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, aura

I'm building a realtime update aura component, this component works just fine in browser but is not working on mobile, I'm using **lightning:empApi** but according to the documentation this doesn't work salesforce1, Does anyone have a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_sh_social_hub.htm&type=5 did you tried this?

Comment: The best you can do is use normal "events": https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_one.htm . For real-time async updates on mobile, you'd have to write your own code via Mobile SDK (i.e. develop your own mobile app)